# Custom layer for Simple Exponential Smoothing

Tags: neural-network, keras, time-series

I am writing a test custom layer which implements the Simple Exponential Smoothing algorithm.
The problem: when I train it, the alpha (smoothing) coefficient always converges to value 1. This means that the one step forward forecast always takes the previous actual value.
I most probably miss something obvious but couldn't figure it out, yet.
Any idea? Thanks.

The code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class SES(Layer):
    def __init__(self, dtype=tf.float32):
        super(SES, self).__init__()
    def build(self, input_shape):
        alpha_init = tf.keras.initializers.random_uniform(minval=0., maxval=1.)
        self.alpha = tf.Variable(name="alpha", initial_value=alpha_init(shape=(1,),dtype='float32'),
                                 constraint=tf.keras.constraints.min_max_norm(0,1),trainable=True)
        
    def call(self, inputs): 
        '''SES formula: yhat (one step fwd) = alpha*y_previous (aka actual_previous) + (1-alpha)* yhat_previous'''
        def predict_one_step(y_previous, alpha, yhat_previous):
            yhat = (alpha*y_previous) + ((1-alpha)*yhat_previous)
            
            return yhat #prediction one step ahead
        
        predictions = []
        for timestep in range(inputs.shape[0]):
            if timestep == 0: 
                yhat_previous = inputs[timestep]
            
            yhat = predict_one_step(inputs[timestep], self.alpha, yhat_previous)
            yhat_previous = yhat
            
            predictions.append(yhat)
            
        return tf.concat(predictions, axis=-1)


--------------------- SES training loss --------------------
Loss at epoch 000: 0.439, alpha: 0.250
Loss at epoch 020: 0.226, alpha: 0.433
Loss at epoch 040: 0.129, alpha: 0.581
Loss at epoch 060: 0.069, alpha: 0.705
Loss at epoch 080: 0.031, alpha: 0.810
Loss at epoch 100: 0.011, alpha: 0.892
Loss at epoch 120: 0.003, alpha: 0.949
Loss at epoch 140: 0.000, alpha: 0.981
Loss at epoch 160: 0.000, alpha: 0.995
Loss at epoch 180: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 200: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 220: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 240: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 260: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 280: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 300: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 320: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 340: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 360: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 380: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 400: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 420: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 440: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 460: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Loss at epoch 480: 0.000, alpha: 1.000
Final loss: 0.000
alpha = 1.000
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `inputs[timestep]` instead of `inputs[timestep - 1]` as `y_previous` in the `call` method, which is why the loss is exactly zero when `alpha` is equal to one. This has been fixed in the code below.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class SES(Layer):

    def __init__(self, dtype=tf.float32):
        super(SES, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):

        alpha_init = tf.keras.initializers.random_uniform(minval=0., maxval=1.)

        self.alpha = tf.Variable(
            name="alpha",
            initial_value=alpha_init(shape=(1,), dtype='float32'),
            constraint=tf.keras.constraints.min_max_norm(0, 1),
            trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):

        def predict_one_step(y_previous, alpha, yhat_previous):
            return alpha * y_previous + (1 - alpha) * yhat_previous

        ### original
        #yhat_previous = inputs[0]
        #predictions = [yhat_previous]

        ### proposed modification ###
        yhat_previous = [inputs[0]]
        predictions = [tf.convert_to_tensor(yhat_previous, dtype='float32')]

        for timestep in range(1, inputs.shape[0]):

            yhat = predict_one_step(inputs[timestep - 1], self.alpha, yhat_previous)

            yhat_previous = yhat
            predictions.append(yhat)

        return tf.concat(predictions, axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, indeed this is the problem and I corrected it in my code. Missed indeed something obvious. I tried also your code directly but it generates an error at the final concatenation: ---> 32 return tf.concat(predictions, axis=-1) ==> InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Expected concatenating dimensions in the range [0, 0), but got -1 [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat. It has something to do with the first tensor in the predictions list, I believe.

Comment: If you want you can add the data and the code that you are using for training in the text of your question and I will take a look, assuming that you haven't resolved this yourself already.

Comment: It worked with the following modification to your code:         yhat_previous = [inputs[0]]
        predictions = [tf.convert_to_tensor(yhat_previous, dtype='float32')]. Please view above.